# Set File for upload on a type="file" html element

Tags: c#, html, vb.net, upload, input-type-file

I've been researching this for a couple of days now and have made no headway regarding a possible way of doing this.

Programmatically I've been able to invoke the "Choose File to Upload" dialog but whenever it inputs the File and Path and try to submit it it will not accept the input value.

```
WebBrowser.Document.GetElementById("field-file").InvokeMember("click")
```

Allows the .click() method to fire.

Whenever I submit it, it gives me an error that the field must be filled.
Is there another Event that I need to invoke before submitting it?

As I understand the value properties of this input type is disabled for security reasons - but surely it's just a matter finding a workaround?

Comment: Any "workaround" you may find will be a serious security flaw in a specific browser, not something you can and should rely upon to do whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: No, there is no automatic way with JavaScript code to "steal" a file from somebody's computer without asking them.  If you find such a workaround, please report it to the browser vendor's bug list immediately.

Comment: I'm not trying to "steal" a file - I'm trying to upload a file from my PC to a Website I have access to whenever the file changes on my PC. Unfortunately the only way I'm able to do this currently is to select the file myself. But since I'm not always at my desk I was looking for a way to do this automatically.

Comment: Why don't you use a file sharing service instead of a web page?

Comment: Unfortunately it will not be possible. The file needs to be updated and then uploaded for parsing by the hosting site.

Comment: Okay. I suggest, you start a new question and describe your whole problem without proposing the web page solution from this question. I'm sure you will get useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

As you say "for security reasons". So, there should not be a workaround. Otherwise it would be a security flaw, that [is not intended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input#File_inputs) and will surely be fixed.

On the other hand, W3C defines the [following](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4.1):

> User agents may use the value of the value attribute as the initial
>   file name.

But I do not know any current browser that supports this.

Comment: I have found a method of doing this without user interaction - thank you for the helpful answers. Luckily I don't believe in "It cannot be done".

Comment: Okay. If your solution still fits the same question, we would be also lucky when you share it with us.

Comment: The only method found that works was by using the SendKeys.SendWait function to "simulate" a user. I used a series of FindWindows tests to determine if the Dialog was in fact visible populated the field required and returned the information to the html form. I then tested for the acceptance of this file by testing htmlelement's value and then submitting the form. A bit crude, but functional. It will suffice for now.